# File test inside case statement ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to do a file test in a case statement, I want something like:

```
case ARGV[0]
when File.exist?
  puts "File exists!"
when ""
  puts "No argument"
end
```

This doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: If it's a boolean I see no reason to use a `case` statement, and at least one reason not to. `case` statements imply selecting from an arbitrarily long list of options, which don't exist here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of what the `case` does:

```
case ARGV[0]
when File.exist?(ARGV[0])  # Note proper syntax for File.exist?
  puts "File exists!"   # Do this if value of ARGV[0] == result of File.exist?
when ""
  puts "No argument"    # Do this if value of ARGV[0] == ""
end
```

Clearly this will not work if `ARGV[0]` is not blank. In addition, it will still execute `File.exist?(ARGV[0])` regardless of the value of `ARGV[0]` so it doesn't do as you probably intend.

I am supposing that you're wanting to check if the file exists after knowing the argument is not nil or blank:

```
if ARGV[0] and not ARGV[0].empty?
   puts "File exists!" if File.exist?(ARGV[0])
else
   puts "No argument"
end
```

If `ARGV[0]` has a value but file does not exist, you still have no output. I don't know if that's what's intended based upon your question since you didn't express intended behavior.

You could also do something like this:

```
case ARGV[0]
when "", nil
   puts "No argument"
else
   puts "File exists!" if File.exist?(ARGV[0])
end
```

Comment: `File.exist?` requires an argument

Comment: @Stefan indeed, it does. Sorry I was being a little lazy. I was just mimicking whatever the OP had here since the syntax of `File.exist?` didn't bear on the main point. But good catch, I'll update accordingly.